# How to use DNN to fit these data

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I'm using DNN to fit these data, and I use softmax to classify them into 2 class, and each of them has a demensity of 4040, can someone with experience tell me what's wrong with my nets.

It is strange that my initial loss is 7.6 and my initial error is 0.5524, and Basically they won't change anymore.

```
for train, test in kfold.split(data_pro, valence_labels):
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(5000,activation='relu',input_shape=(4040,)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.25))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(500, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.5))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.5))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.5))
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.0001,rho=0.9),
               loss='binary_crossentropy',
               metrics=['accuracy'])

print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
print(f'Training for fold {fold_no} ...')

log_dir="logs/fit/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)

# Fit data to model
history = model.fit(data_pro[train], valence_labels[train],
          batch_size=128,
          epochs=50,
          verbose=1,
          callbacks=[tensorboard_callback]
          )

# Generate generalization metrics
scores = model.evaluate(data_pro[test], valence_labels[test], verbose=0)
print(f'Score for fold {fold_no}: {model.metrics_names[0]} of {scores[0]}; {model.metrics_names[1]} of {scores[1]*100}%')
acc_per_fold.append(scores[1] * 100)
loss_per_fold.append(scores[0])

# Increase fold number
fold_no = fold_no + 1

# == Provide average scores ==
print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
print('Score per fold')
for i in range(0, len(acc_per_fold)):
    print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print(f'> Fold {i+1} - Loss: {loss_per_fold[i]} - Accuracy: {acc_per_fold[i]}%')
print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
print('Average scores for all folds:')
print(f'> Accuracy: {np.mean(acc_per_fold)} (+- {np.std(acc_per_fold)})')
print(f'> Loss: {np.mean(loss_per_fold)}')
print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't add `Dropout` after the final `Dense` , delete the `model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.5))`

And I think your code may raise error because your `labels`'s dim is 1 , But your final `Dense`'s `units` is 2 . Change `model.add(keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))` to `model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))`

Read [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner) to learn `tensorflow`

Update 1 :

Change

```
model.compile(optimizer= tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate = 0.00001,momentum=0.9,nesterov=True),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

to

```
model.compile(optimizer= tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=3e-4),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And change

```
accAll = []
for epoch in range(1, 50):
    model.fit(train_data, train_labels,
             batch_size=50,epochs=5,
             validation_data = (val_data, val_labels))
    val_loss, val_Accuracy = model.evaluate(val_data,val_labels,batch_size=1)
    accAll.append(val_Accuracy)
```

to

```
accAll = model.fit(
    train_data, train_labels,
    batch_size=50,epochs=20,
    validation_data = (val_data, val_labels)
)
```

Comment: 可以帮忙看一下新的问题吗,那个数据一直没弄对，谢谢啦

Comment: @CMZ Can you give a google colab link with your code ?

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1C5FCzxKt5IYEZd_PRNPSxNPXwB9T1moP?usp=sharing               here are my codes

Comment: @CMZ , Your initial loss is 0.8259 . After training , it becomes to 0.6363 . It changes .

Comment: @CMZ , you can try my code to see whether it could lead to a better result .